# How to fetch spinner item from Compound Control android spinner class to main activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am trying to get the item value from a custom compound spinner which is rendered on the main activity. In the output its possible to select the drop down list of spinner but the item catch is not happen please give me solution below is the code snippet.

custom/compound control class

```
 public class CompounControlSpinner extends Spinner {
    private String[] items = { 
            "Google", "IBM", "Microsoft", "Accenture", "Cisco", "Dell", "Oracle", "Facebook"
    };
    public ComContSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items));
        this.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
    }

}
```

Main xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mysmax.compouncontrolspinner.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Select Your Company" />

    <com.mysmax.compouncontrolspinner.ComContSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Done" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new CompounControlSpinner(this, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

please any one suggest me how to fetch the data in the main activity from spinner when I select the item it should dynamically update in main activity. Advance thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...when I select the item it should dynamically update in main
>   activity.

As you get the Activity reference in your custom view you could simply use it, as an interface, to communicate back with it when a selection event happens(and pass the selected value). You could this like below:

```
public interface SelectionHappened {

    void onSelection(String newSelectedItem);
}
```

The activity would need to implement this interface:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SelectionHappened {
    //... current code

    @Override
    public void onSelection(String newSelectedItem) {
         // when this method is triggered the user selected something in the Spinner   
    }

}
```

The last item is to send the event from the custom view:

```
public class CompounControlSpinner extends Spinner {
    private SelectionHappened mListener; 
    private String[] items = { 
            "Google", "IBM", "Microsoft", "Accenture", "Cisco", "Dell", "Oracle", "Facebook"
    };
    public ComContSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mListener = (SelectionHappened) context;
        this.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items));
        this.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                  mListener.onSelection((String)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)); // send the event to the activity 
            }
        //... rest of the current code
```

Comment: In compound class onselection with param throws null pointer exception but the string is not null.

Comment: @user2627142 Break the line in my code in separate lines and see on which one you get the exception(like https://gist.github.com/luksprog/54dbdc7c2c87cf23d476). That exception shouldn't happen if you followed my code.

Comment: 09-30 14:27:36.654: E/AndroidRuntime(1188): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
14:27:36.654:E/AndroidRuntime(1188):java.lang.NullPointerException
09-30 14:27:36.654: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):  at com.mysmax.compouncontrolspinner.ComContSpinner$1.onItemSelected(ComContSpinner.java:30)
14:27:36.654: E/AndroidRuntime(1188): at widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:893)
09-30 14:27:36.654: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):  at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:48)
09-30 14:27:36.654: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):  at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:861)

Comment: I checked with new piece of code that you have shared. Thanks. But its failing. Any other solutions.

Comment: @user2627142 I've told you to use the code above to see what line exactly throws the exception(instead of having one big line). Posting that stacktrace doesn't tell me anything because I can't see which is line 30 in ComContSpinner and what is null there.

Comment: check in this link https://github.com/chethanrgowda/compound_control_spinner/blob/master/SpinnerCompounControl/src/com/example/spinnercompouncontrol/ComContSpinner.java

Comment: @user2627142 You didn't copied my code exactly, you missed the line `mListener = (SelectionHappened) context;` in the CompounControlSpinner constructor.